# Run external python script and let the console show in a kivy grid

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Would it be possible to add a console for a script to a grid in kivy? And if it is how would I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want an actual console? Or do you just want to show the output of a script that you are running?

Comment: Yes @JohnAnderson, he wants the output of the console in the kivy. Also yeah! it's possible...

Comment: You can use `process = subprocess.Popen()` to run the script, and read the output using `process.stdout.readline()`. The output could be displayed in a readonly `TextInput`. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

Comment: @JohnAnderson It doesn't matter between either I get the output or the console. As long as it runs on any platform. So I do believe subproccess is not going to work for me